# Get PropertyDb for SVF2

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have been trying to get the PropertyDb for the new SVF2 format.
Currently it seems that the data in the PropertyDb and when getting properties through [endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) is different, or am I missing something?

If it correct that the endpoint gives the data from the new SVF2, but the downloadable PropertyDb is still SVF data? If yes, is there a way to download the SVF2 propertyDb?

Answer (score 0):

SVF2 has no propertyDB file per say, so it is different from SVF. At least the way way SVF2 creates its properties files is different from SVF, and highly more difficult to d/l and interpret.

However, if you read the model manifest, whether it is SVF or SVF2, you'll find an entry which tells you where is the SVF Property DB file, and that did not change. But that sounds not what you are asking.

Next, the endpoint you mentioned should be working like before (no change) - the only difference is that if you requested a SVF translation, that endpoint will use SVF db ID, and if you requested a SVF2 translation, that endpoint will use SVF2 db ID.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
The reason I am currently using the propertyDb is because of unit issues in IFC files (metric files turning into imperial), and therefore using the propertyDb where the data has not been preprocessed, and with that being able to get correct values.
But with what you are saying, then there is no chance to get the 'un-processed' data from an SVF2 file?
If yes, then I guess the only method is to keep using the SVF propertyDb and work with the ID remapping in the viewer - even though that seems like a big work-around.

Comment: the db id mapping is a direct way to match both side - but the recommend way (which is the indirect way) is to use the external ids. But that will probably not work for IFC, since IFC does not support unique IDs.