# Units for SVF2 data

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have previously been using the property.db to get properties and metadata from SVF files.
I have been told this will not be possible for SVF2 files here: [Get PropertyDb for SVF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68373822/get-propertydb-for-svf2). I have therefore been trying with the getProperties endpoint again to test out with the SVF2 format and getting properties [{urn}/metadata/{guid}/properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/). This however still gives me a challenge that was the main reason for originally moving away from that endpoint, being that the units in the properties are changed from the files originally metric to imperial.

So, now I would like to know if one of the two following things is something you have a solution for:

1. Getting the property.db for SVF2 files (seems this is not how SVF is structured and will therefore not be possible?)
2. Get original units for files with the getProperty endpoints

Only looking for solutions of getting properties without having to load model into a viewer.

The file tested for now is an IFC from Tekla.

Thank you for any help or guidance!

Answer (score 0):

The unit depends on which IFC conversion method, legacy or modern, you're using. (I tested one Tekla IFC file I have.)

1. Leacgy: it's using SI unit, mm.
2. Modern: it's using Imperial unit, ft.

There is no PropertyDB SQLite file that comes with SVF2. It is generated with SVF. So, if no SVF is generated, there is no PropertyDB SQLite file.

We're collecting the customers' non-confidential use cases of using the PropertyDB SQLite file. Could you share more details with me? Looks that you use it because there are no units returned by the [GET properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) API, am I correct?

(If you cannot post the info. publicly, please use forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com instead)

BTW, you can take advantage of the optimized viewer PropertyDB `json.gz` files as a workaround. Here is a sample demonstrating this idea:

https://github.com/cyrillef/webhooks-properties#property-server

Comment: Sorry Eason, my comment was too long, so it had to be in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Eason King, sorry my reply is too long in comment, so it will be as another answer.

So, as I hear it there are currently no method for me to get the properties of model in the correct metric units for 'Modern' conversion SVF2 files?
Is this something you will be looking into making possible?
(I did not look into the property-server workaround, but since you describe it as a "optimized viewer PropertyDB" I assume it is still only for SVF?).
Because of the unit issues we also previously used 'Legacy' converter, but since there is also a fair bit of issues with that one, we moved away from that.

I can for sure share a bit. I am using the PropertyDB SQLite file exactly because we need to get file data in the correct units. We could in theory "just" convert the results from the GET properties, but since it has been reformatted and rounded, the results will no longer be precise. Therefore we have chosen to work with the propertyDB.
Since this is no longer a solution for SVF2 we are really in doubt about how we can get a sufficient result, and at the moment it seems like there are simply no solution.

Comment: Thanks Esben, Both SVF & SVF2 have the optimized viewer PropertyDB generated. Currently, the modern conversion method is using Revit IFC to parse the file, so the unit will be Imperial unit. Currently, GET properties API doesn't support override property unit.

Comment: To your PropertyDB SQLite file use case, sounds that you want to get property data without reformating, rounding and units as [Viewer3D#getProperties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#getproperties-dbid-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) does, right?

Comment: Correct. Getting the property without any kind of rounding and units would be the optimal solution, because we then would be able to handle them as we see best fit.